# Use the measurement standards or give users the choice

Tags: units-of-measurement

I deal with measurements in my application (height, weight, etc). All of the equations I've found use the international standards (kg, cm). I can easily do the conversions in the code, but I'm wondering if I give users the option or do I make them do the conversions themselves if they don't wish to use the standard?

Some similar programs I've seen (from the U.S.) only allow feet and inches for height and pounds for weight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more (that is, whether your application's users prefer metric over U.S. units or vice versa, and probably the 
geographic scope of those users, or whether one unit system is more "authoritative" than another), it would be appropriate to give users the choice of measurement system.

If you want to use both international (kg and cm) and U.S. standards (feet, inches, and pounds), you should try defining 
a base unit, which is the smallest unit representable in both unit systems, and perform operations on those base units rather
than on metric or U.S. units. See this question: [Metric and Imperial internal representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312701/metric-and-imperial-internal-representation)
This can be important if, for example, your application receives or measures heights and weights that could be in either metric or U.S.
units.

Comment: Thanks for this and the link. I will provide the choice, but for my application the accuracy is not that important and I will allow rounding to occur.